# Odoo - Add page number in qweb report

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-9, qweb

```
<ul class="list-inline">
 <li>Page:</li>
 <li><span class="page"/></li>
 <li>/</li>
 <li><span class="topage"/></li>
</ul>
```

This displays page number at the footer of the report. But is it possible to display page number, if I want page number as a field in the report like:

Transaction #:
Account #:
Page:
Date: 10-March-2017
Time: 12:28:32 PM

Comment: Means that you want to take one field and inside add the single custom page number and this page number shown in the footer section. Right?

Answer (score -1):

Up till Odoo 10c, putting the page number automatically in the body of the report is not possible. A ticket has been opened on GitHub: [[9.0] Page number cannot be used in Body of QWeb report #13332](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/13332)

However, it is not a bug in a sense because it works, but it would be nice if it could be placed elsewhere in the body than just the footer.

Also, this has to do with the way the reports and report numbers are generated. The footer appears in every page, which the report generator uses to determine the total number of pages and the current page number.

Answer (score -1):

- Please try this code for page number in Qweb-report. It will
  automatically display page no.

  `<t t-call="report.external_layout"></t>`

Answer (score -2):

```
<ul class="list-inline">
 <li>Page:</li>
 <li><span class="page"/></li>
 <li>/</li>
 <li><span class="topage"/></li>
</ul>
```

add this code to inside the header tag which place do you want